# Why the value of PRI is different in ps and top?

Tags: process, ps, top

nginx PID is `19910`

1. The value is **19** in `ps -eo pri`

   ```
    ps -eo pid,ppid,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,cmd |head -n1;ps -eo pid,ppid,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,cmd |grep nginx
      PID  PPID  NI PRI PSR %CPU STAT CMD
    19910     1   0  19   0  0.0 Ss   nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
    19911 19910   0  19   2  0.0 S    nginx: worker process
    19912 19910   0  19   1  0.0 S    nginx: worker process
    19914 19910   0  19   1  0.0 S    nginx: worker process
    19915 19910   0  19   0  0.0 S    nginx: worker process
   ```
2. The value is **80** in `ps -elf`

   ```
    ps -elf |head -n1;ps -elf |grep nginx
    F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
    5 S root     19910     1  0  80   0 - 21487 sigsus Jul29 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
    5 S www-data 19911 19910  0  80   0 - 21576 ep_pol Jul29 ?        00:01:55 nginx: worker process
    5 S www-data 19912 19910  0  80   0 - 21576 ep_pol Jul29 ?        00:02:05 nginx: worker process
    5 S www-data 19914 19910  0  80   0 - 21576 ep_pol Jul29 ?        00:02:00 nginx: worker process
    5 S www-data 19915 19910  0  80   0 - 21576 ep_pol Jul29 ?        00:02:08 nginx: worker process
   ```
3. The value is **20** in `top -b -n 1 -p`

   ```
    top -b -n 1 -p 19910                              
    top - 09:57:13 up 435 days, 19 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
    Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
    %Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
    KiB Mem:   8175360 total,  4617480 used,  3557880 free,   167444 buffers
    KiB Swap:  8384508 total,    10408 used,  8374100 free.  3955108 cached Mem

      PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    19910 root      20   0   85948   2944   1784 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nginx
   ```

My question is as follows:

1. Why the output is totally different in two different `ps` command?
2. What's the difference of `PRI` between `ps` and `top`?

I'll appreciate if anyone can explain it to me.

Answer (score 2):

Accoring to [this](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/issues/111):

`top` print the raw value of `priority`, which is column 18 of `/proc/[pid]/stat`,thus the output is **20**

`ps -eo pri` print the the value of `pri`, which is equal to `39 - priority`,thus the output is `39 -20 = 19`

`ps -l`, `-l` option print the value of `opri`,which is equal to `60 + priority`，thus the output is '60 + 20 = 80'

Comment: There is no answer in the past few days, and I find out the reason, so I post the answer myself.